# How do we sort fields of documents in collections on mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to sort the documents in the collections, I know the documents are saved in FIFO. But I want the documents to be saved as per my convenience.

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Users.create({
    firstName: req.body.firstName
  })
    .then((user) => {
        user.password = user.generateHash(req.body.password);
        user.save();
        console.log('User created ', user);
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.json(user);
    }, (err) => next(err))
    .catch((err) => next(err));
});
```

From the above code, the documents are saved as follows:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d40914a59b5775718f13f9e"),
        "firstName" : "final8",
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-07-30T18:49:46.549Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-07-30T18:49:46.604Z"),
        "__v" : 0,
        "password" : 
        "$2b$08$H1cxDRUWDEDlcy.ZspiiKuzIXnOiAsrFtPywXnYDIqYa00xp1VTQG"
}
```

where as I want them to be saved as:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d4083b78ead7e648c1e733d"),
        "firstName" : "final",
        "password" : 
        "$2b$08$JjKUhsH5w0YN/PyyDPUaLOX3kffuZfqKMz8IU6r0UiD.1m9xRQHtm",`
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-07-30T18:49:46.549Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-07-30T18:49:46.604Z"),
        "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: Change your schema to that sequence as you want.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work that way. I already tried